# how action buttons works in Angular 6-json-schema-form

Tags: angular, formarray, formgroups, angular6-json-schema-form

I am trying to understand below JSON base form. I am not able to figure out from where that yellow button "Add Phone number" comes from and how it trigger event to replicate more phone list

https://hamidihamza.com/Angular6-json-schema-form/?set=ng-jsf&example=ng-jsf-flex-layout&framework=material-design&language=en

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a [reactive form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) - check the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wuphzz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css) here

The whole form is a FormBuilder group which consists of:

- FormControls for the static (non-repeatable) part of the form (firstName, lastName etc.)
- While the phone numbers are Formbuilder Array. Everytime that the 'Add phone number' button is clicked, an element is added to our Formbuilder Array.
- When you click save, you get the whole form in json (check console)